# Transfering Word table of contents into HTML-Code

Tags: html

I want to transfer a table of contents from Word into HTML-Code.

[Table of Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7boE4.png)

Im wondering, how to realise those dots between the page name and the page number because the lenght of the page names can vary.

Is there also a way for me to make the table dynamic? For exmaple I'm writing something in a h1-tag and it automatically fills the content of the tag + the page number with this layout into the table of contents?

So far I'm clueless on what to do, can someone please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Danny, from office you can export your document as html. The image you show though is not a table, it's just lines with dots. You should create a proper table in order to have one when you export. Otherwise start with html table directly. The second request is not quite clear to me, maybe you'll need some javascript for that. Good luck!